# CRM SItecore Connection - Dynamics Connector

Tags: xconnect, dynamics-crm-module

I am Working on **Sitecore 9.0.2** and **Dynamics Connector 2.0.1**.

As I started using Custom Model in my endpoint to sync custom data from `CRM` to Sitecore my default `sync` stopped working i.e. Name , Email these fields are not getting synced anymore.

Any Idea on this issue ?

Comment: did you deploy tyour custom xconnect model?

Comment: Hey @VladIobagiu, I got it working actually the custom model was just having the new facet and not the default ones so it was never mapping it.

Comment: I would really appreciate any help from you to sync a dropdown type field.As in the value saved in my XDB needs to be mappped to CRM field which is a dropdown. Any suggestions on how I can map that? Unable to do it for dropdown field while it works fine with text type.

Comment: hey @VladIobagiu could please guide me on mapping dropdown values for Sync ? just like Gender, i have few custom fields of dropdown type that needs to be mapped in CRM from XDB. Is it possible  to do so using existing functionlaity ? if not can you please share some documnetation on how to create the readers and writers for it and also the mappings for such scenario ?